# Returning method without passing a value in it - Java

Tags: java, methods, return

I have a method returning an integer. My question is how to get this number 
like

`int d = returning value of customerperminute methods;`

Thanks in advance

```
public int customerperminute(){
    Random R = new Random();
    int r = R.nextInt(4-0);
    if (r==0||r==1){
        return 0;
    }
    if (r==2){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Huh?  Your question does not make sense.

Comment: As you told `int d = customerperminute();`

Comment: have you tried: 
int d = customerperminute(); 
?

Comment: ah guys sorry 
the problem was that i forgot to make static method

Comment: it should be public static int ...... 
sorry for such stupid question ... 
thank you all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose the class in which this method is defined is **ABC** and let's say **customerperminuteStat**, which is static method.

```
class ABC{
    public int customerperminute(){
        Random R = new Random();
        int r = R.nextInt(4-0);
        if (r==0||r==1){
            return 0;
        }
        if (r==2){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 2;
        }    
    }
    public static int customerperminuteStat(){
        Random R = new Random();
        int r = R.nextInt(4-0);
        if (r==0||r==1){
            return 0;
        }
        if (r==2){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 2;
        }    
    }
}
```

this is just class definition with it's methods.

To retrieve value from the function is to **call the method**.

***Static Method, say *customerperminuteStat* can be called from any type method(static/instance). But the non-static, say instance eg. *customerperminute* can be called from only instance methods.***

---

***Calling***

1. from the method of same class

int d = customerperminute();
int e = customerperminuteStat();

1. from the method of some other class

int d = customerperminute();
int e = customerperminuteStat();

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke method like this: `int d = customerperminute();`

Comment: Ah .. finally you got the question ;) +1.

Comment: yes i tried this first but it did not work because the method is nonstatic i make it static everything work thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1)Invoke it directly in **non-static methods**:

`int value = customerperminute();`

2)Invoke it in **static method**, add `static` in the method signature:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(customerperminute());
    }

    public static int customerperminute() {
        Random R = new Random();
        int r = R.nextInt(4 - 0);
        if (r == 0 || r == 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (r == 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in `main()` method

```
public static void main(String s[]){
 ABC inst = new ABC(); //create instance of class which contains called method
 int d = customerperminute();
}
```

or make `customerperminute()` as static & you can directly call it using class name `ABC.customerperminute()` if method is in different class or directly as `customerperminute()` if method is in same class as `main()` method